# Create nested object from 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a 3 sets of data:

```
let data1 = [ {key: value1}, {key: value2}, {key:value3} ]
let data2 = [ {key: value1}, {key: value2}, {key:value3}, {key: value4} ] //same structure, different values
let data3 = [ [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1] ]
```

I would like the following data structure:

```
result = {
           data1[0][key] : {
              data2[0][key2] : data3[0][0],
              data2[0][key2] : data3[0][0],
              data2[0][key2] : data3[0][0]
         }
```

I would like to do something like this, but it's not working:

```
let result = {};
data1.map( (d, i) => {
     data3[i].map(
       (x,idx) => (
        result[d.key] = {
          data2[i]['key'] : x
         }
       )
      ) 
})
```

Comment: What is `title`? You have a syntax error (also in your answer).

Comment: @trincot fixed :) running on too little sleep haha

Comment: Still syntax error -- parentheses don't match -- misplaced. Also in your answer. You surely didn't test that code. Proper indentation would highlight that.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, fixed:

```
let result = {};
data1.map((d, i) => {
  result[d.key] = {};
  data3[i].map((x, idx) => (result[d.key][data2[idx]["key"]] = x));
});
```